# Choosing a class with max probability for every bootstrap sample

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics-bootstrap

i'm trying to run a query creating a for loop for creating bootstraps with data from package rattle.data (weather data with RainTomorrow as the target column). I'm trying to choose a class with maximum probability for every single bootstrap sample, then predicting the class with maximum votes.

With this code I keep getting back an error

```
if(!require(rpart)) install.packages("rpart") 
if(!require(rpart.plot)) install.packages("rpart.plot") 
if(!require(caret)) install.packages("caret") 
if(!require(rattle.data)) install.packages("rattle.data") 
if(!require(tidyverse)) install.packages("tidyverse") 
if(!require(ipred)) install.packages("ipred") 
if(!require(Metrics)) install.packages("Metrics") 
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)
library(rattle.data)
library(tidyverse)
library(caret)
library(ipred)
library(Metrics)

set.seed(500)

data <- weather

# creating train and test data
index <- createDataPartition(data$RainTomorrow, p = .6, list = FALSE)
train_data <- data[ index, ]
test_data <- data[-index, ]

## b ukol -> error in for each loop
nBoot = 10 #nr bootstrap samples

#create empty matrix [nr test data x nr bootstrap samples]to store bootstrap predictions
pred = matrix(data = NA, nrow = nrow(test_data), ncol = nBoot)

train_controls = rpart.control(minsplit = 6, maxdepth = 3)

for(b in 1:nBoot){
  #create bootstrap sample
  index.boot = sample(x=nrow(train_data), replace = T, size = nrow(train_data)) 
  data_boot = train_data[index.boot,]
  #fit data for the bootstrap sample
  boot.model  = rpart(RainTomorrow ~ ., 
                      data =data_boot, 
                      method = "anova", 
                      control = train_controls)
  #rpart.plot(boot.model)
  #save prediction for bootstrap
  pred[,b] = predict(boot.model, newdata= test_data )
}

#calculate prediction as mean of bootstrap predictions 

pred.bagged = rowMeans(pred)
print(rmse(actual = test_data$RainTomorrow, predicted = pred.bagged))
```

but running this query gives me back a warning message:

> In Ops.factor(actual, predicted) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors

and I cannot for the life of me figure the reason (newbie in machine learning).

EDIT: still looking for a valid answer

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you are trying to calculate RMSE from a factor:

```
pred.bagged = rowMeans(pred)
class(pred.bagged)
[1] "numeric"
class(test_data$RainTomorrow)
[1] "factor"
```

you can convert the factor to numeric, which is what rpart did when you specified method = "anova", and calculate RMSE:

```
rmse(actual = as.numeric(test_data$RainTomorrow), predicted = pred.bagged)
```

RMSE is normally used for regression and it doesn't make much sense for a classification model. For classification, you would use method="class" and for evaluating use accuracy, f1 or cohen's kappa, you can see example below with confusionMatrix from caret:

```
for(b in 1:nBoot){
  #create bootstrap sample
  index.boot = sample(x=nrow(train_data), replace = T) 
  data_boot = train_data[index.boot,]
  #fit data for the bootstrap sample
  boot.model  = rpart(RainTomorrow ~ ., 
                      data =data_boot, 
                      method = "class", 
                      control = train_controls)
  #rpart.plot(boot.model)
  #save prediction for bootstrap
  pred[,b] = as.character(predict(boot.model, newdata= test_data ,type="class"))
}

# very crude way to get majority vote
pred.bagged = apply(pred,1,function(i){
names(sort(table(factor(i,levels=c("No","Yes")))))[2]
})
# convert to a factor, same levels as test_data$RainTomorrow
pred.bagged = factor(pred.bagged,levels=c("No","Yes"))

confusionMatrix(,test_data$RainTomorrow)
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction  No Yes
       No  120   0
       Yes   0  26

               Accuracy : 1          
                 95% CI : (0.9751, 1)
    No Information Rate : 0.8219     
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 3.672e-13  

                  Kappa : 1          

 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : NA         

            Sensitivity : 1.0000     
            Specificity : 1.0000     
         Pos Pred Value : 1.0000     
         Neg Pred Value : 1.0000     
             Prevalence : 0.8219     
         Detection Rate : 0.8219     
   Detection Prevalence : 0.8219     
      Balanced Accuracy : 1.0000     

       'Positive' Class : No
```